# How to recover data from a file as if it were an 'od -D filename' in linux terminal

Tags: c++, ifstream

I have a file of type: data, and I want to read that file the same way I see the contents of the file with the command

od -D filename on Linux

In other words, the contents of the file are:

```
0000000 000002 000000 000002 000000 000002 000000 000002 000000
0000020 000004 000000 000004 000000 000004 000000 000004 000000
0000040 000006 000000 000006 000000 000006 000000 000006 000000
0000060
```

But with the od -D filename command on Linux, I see:

```
0000000 2 2 2 2
0000020 4 4 4 4
0000040 6 6 6 6
0000060
```

I want to read this file in C ++ so that I don't have to manipulate the data, but simply retrieve 222244446666

In the code below I am reading in a way that works, but if the file contains values ​​= 0, I will not be able to rescue them in the reading.

```
ifstream file2 (file, ios :: in);
        char ch;
        if (file2.is_open ())
        {
            while (! file2.eof ())
            {
                file2.get (ch);
                double num = ch;
                //if (num != 0) {
                    cout << num << endl;
                //}
            }
        }
        file2.close ();
```

When I read this way it looks like:

```
2
0
0
0
2
0
0
0
2
0
0
0
2
0
0
0
4
0
0
0
4
0
0
0
4
0
0
0
4
0
0
0
6
0
0
0
6
0
0
0
6
0
0
0
6
0
0
0
0
```

I want to know how I can read this file so that it only takes the real values, that is, 222244446666, but if it contains 0 values I also need to get them. Example: 000022224444 (That is why I commented if num != 0, this doesn't work for all cases)

That is, I need to eliminate these zeros as the od -D filename command does

Comment: Is that `od -d`?

Comment: it works with od -D filename

Comment: `while (! file2.eof ())` is [always a bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-i-e-while-stream-eof-cons); also, what exactly do you expect to accomplish by converting each byte into a `double`? Why do you think you need to do that?

Comment: because I will put the data from the file on a data structure.

Answer (score 0):

The data looks like 32 bit binary integers in little endian (PC) format. The octal dump is a bit misleading because you instruct it with `-D` to read 16 bit values. A 16 bit int with the value 2 is the byte sequence 0x2 0x0, but as an octal integer it is 2 (or, if we print leading 0s, 000002).

If you read it byte by byte your would see that.

The solution to your problem is to simply `fread` 32 bit ints, provided you are on in Intel compatible platform.